# SQL INSERT Statement By Comparing and Retrieving Data Involving Multiple Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
+----+------------------+------------------+--------------+
| ID | EmployeeUsername |  EmployeeEmail   | ManagerEmail |
+----+------------------+------------------+--------------+
|  1 | Ron_UN           |   ron@mail.com   | pat@mail.com |
|  2 | Pat_UN           |   pat@mail.com   |              |    Pat is Ron's Manager.
|  3 | Amy_UN           |   amy@mail.com   | tom@mail.com |   
|  4 | Tom_UN           |   tom@mail.com   |              |    Tom is Amy's Manager.
+----+------------------+------------------+--------------+
```

I would like to insert a new column `ManagerUsername`.

```
+----+------------------+------------------+--------------+-----------------+
| ID | EmployeeUsername |  EmployeeEmail   | ManagerEmail | ManagerUsername | <--
+----+------------------+------------------+--------------+-----------------+
|  1 | Ron_UN           | ron@mail.com     | pat@mail.com |                 |
|  2 | Pat_UN           | pat@mail.com     |              |                 |
|  3 | Amy_UN           | amy@mail.com     | tom@mail.com |                 |
|  4 | Tom_UN           | tom@mail.com     |              |                 |
+----+------------------+------------------+--------------+-----------------+
```

May I know if there is a statement which I can insert into `ManagerUsername` column if `ManagerEmail` belongs to an existing Employee?

```
+----+------------------+------------------+--------------+-----------------+
| ID | EmployeeUsername |  EmployeeEmail   | ManagerEmail | ManagerUsername |
+----+------------------+------------------+--------------+-----------------+
|  1 | Ron_UN           | ron@mail.com     | pat@mail.com | Pat_UN <--      |
|  2 | Pat_UN           | pat@mail.com     |              |                 |
|  3 | Amy_UN           | amy@mail.com     | tom@mail.com | Tom_UN <--      |
|  4 | Tom_UN           | tom@mail.com     |              |                 |
+----+------------------+------------------+--------------+-----------------+
```

I am currently working out the logic of this query, therefore I do not have a SQL statement yet. I will update when I am able to form one.

P.S. Using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can do this with an update self join:

```
UPDATE a
SET ManagerUsername = b.EmployeeUsername;
FROM yourTable a
INNER JOIN yourTable b
    ON a.ManagerEmail = b.EmployeeEmail
```

This assumes that you've already created a new column `ManagerUsername` in your table.  If not, then you'll have to do that first before running the above update.  Note that the update does precisely what you intend, because employee records having no manager email would not self join to anything (probably because they are manager records), and so the manager username for those records would not even be in scope during the update, and the values would remain `NULL`.

Comment: Thank you for the help! I ran the command, but it says Incorrect syntax near 'a'. I can't see anything wrong with the statement on my side.

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near 'a'.

Comment: @gymcode Apologies...I had given you MySQL syntax, when in fact you're using SQL Server.  Always try to tag with the appropriate database when you ask a question here to avoid this.